# Error: parseResponse was not called

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, ajax

I have a an OL3 / geoserver application. Some of my WMS layers have cql_filter. I get the error in the title when trying to select features by doing `request=GetFeature`.
What I have to do is issue multiple requests to the geoserver because I have multiple layers that can be selected. I know I can combine multiple layers into one request and I do that. But some layers have a cql_filter on them already. So for those layers I have to combine existing cql with my intersect cql so my cql looks like this

```
cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((-13002818.055160686 7008876.412750409,-13002818.055160686 7060223.096732896,-12939904.85499688 7060223.096732896,-12939904.85499688 7008876.412750409,-13002818.055160686 7008876.412750409))) AND sdls_id IN (422805982,422805748,414024170,404469091,404365484)
```

There is no issue with my URL's they work and I get response 200 from the server but the ajax is throwing the error. And this error is totally random sometimes they all just work. I have feeling that the problem is with the ajax timing but am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry this is not clear at all.

Comment: Well I issue multiple ajax call in a loop. And randomly some of those calls will throw the error 'Error: parseResponse was not called' even-though there is nothing wrong with my request. As a matter of fact the response is  200 and it formed well.

Comment: Please show your code, ideally as a jsFiddle

Comment: I got it working. Instead of making ajax all at once I create all the URL's first and then execute next one after a previous is done. I thing ajax is confuse when executing multiple requests with the same callback function name.

Comment: `request=GetFeature` is not a WMS operation!